# PySide6 QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

Hello I designed an my UI using Qt Design Studio (Community Edition) and exported it to a `qrc` file then compiled to Python using `pyside6-rcc` then loaded the `main.qml` file inside `main.py` using `"qrc:/main.qml"` resource link but I have these errors `Type App not available`.
This is my file structure;

```
- qml
  - contents
    * App.qml
    * ... // Other Files
  + imports
  * main.qml
  * uifiles.qrc
  * uifiles.py // Generated by [pyside6-rcc uifiles.qrc -o uifiles.py]
* main.py
```

Content of `qml/content/App.qml`;

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import "qrc:/content"
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard

Window {
    width: mainScreen.width
    height: mainScreen.height

    visible: true
    title: "IntelUI"

    Screen01 {
        id: mainScreen
    }
    
    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        property bool showKeyboard :  active
        y: showKeyboard ? parent.height - height : parent.height
        Behavior on y {
            NumberAnimation {
                duration: 200
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }
        anchors.leftMargin: Constants.width/10
        anchors.rightMargin: Constants.width/10
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
    }
}
```

Content of `qml/main.qml`;

```
import QtQuick
import "qrc:/content"

App {
}
```

Content of `main.py`;

```
import sys
import qml.uifiles

from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Errors generated by `python main.py`;

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:7:1: Type App unavailable
qrc:/content/App.qml:42:5: Type Screen01 unavailable
qrc:/content/Screen01.ui.qml:41:13: Type MainStream unavailable
qrc:/content/MainStream.ui.qml:12:1: module "QtQuick.Studio.Components" is not installed
```

Note: I have the following installed `PySide6, PySide6-Addons`

Any help will useful. Thank You!

Comment: Why would you use qml with python?

Comment: It all depends on the type of User Interface you are creating. Then your needs will push you to use a given technology and actually I found myself in love with qml as it got me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Yes, but you do not need python for QML, really.

Comment: To be real to you the truth is that Widgets are not sufficient for my app so I have to create custom UIs and qml is the best i found that works perfectly with PySide6

Comment: Actually I finally found a work around that solved the issue and will be posting the answer soon so that it might help other people with the same issue.

Comment: Why are widgets or qml on its own python without python not sufficient? Just out of curiosity for my understanding the reasons for people using python and javascript-y qml together, both scripting languages of some sort.

Comment: Python is sufficient for backends mainly but here we are talking about frontend and javascript leads in frontend. and the quick reason is because versatility.